# Jetpack compose TextField, is there a way to show a drag handle bubble to move cursor position when editing text?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

When editing a TextField I would like to show a bubble at cursor position like

[image: cursor drag handle]

Comment: It available by default in version `1.1.0-alpha05`. But unfortunately even in `1.0.3` the cursor still doesn't appears.

Comment: It is now available in 1.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible right now.

This handle is represented by the [`TextFieldCursorHandle`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/639a842d6076d3f8788e8f5f7a4ccda12d746010/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/CoreTextField.kt#L817) view.

For it to appear `state.handleState` [must be equal](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/639a842d6076d3f8788e8f5f7a4ccda12d746010/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/CoreTextField.kt#L551) to `HandleState.Cursor`.

At the moment this state is [set](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/639a842d6076d3f8788e8f5f7a4ccda12d746010/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/CoreTextField.kt#L307) only inside the tap handler.

All of these elements are `private` or `internal`, so you can't change this behavior.

I suggest you [open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) on the compose issue tracker.